# Can't perform batch operations after migration

Tags: php, json, parse-platform, parse-server

I've recently completed migrating my Parse PHP application to a Google Cloud-hosted Parse Server. Since then, batch actions like `ParseObject::saveAll()`, `ParseObject::destroyAll()`, etc. started to fail on most cases. I'm thinking about reporting this as a bug on GitHub but I want to ensure it's not just my instance.

I can't even reproduce the [GitHub PHP SDK test code for destroyAll](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-php-sdk/blob/f5a3d5a51337b702af80cc31ff3d28c430a761c8/tests/Parse/ParseObjectTest.php):

```
...
$o1 = ParseObject::create('TestObject');
$o2 = ParseObject::create('TestObject');
$o3 = ParseObject::create('TestObject');
ParseObject::saveAll([$o1, $o2, $o3]);
ParseObject::destroyAll([$o1, $o2, $o3]);
...
```

Both this code and my application's uses of batch actions throw the following kind of exception on PHP (in this example, the error is thrown by saveAll):

> Uncaught exception 'Parse\ParseException' with message 'cannot route batch path /1/classes/TestObject'

Debugging shows that Parse Server returns **error code 107** which according to [the documentation](https://parse.com/docs/dotnet/api/html/T_Parse_ParseException_ErrorCode.htm) means Invalid JSON. I'm not familiar with the REST API, but for this example, the data sent is

> {"requests":[{"method":"POST","path":"/1/classes/TestObject","body":[]},{"method":"POST","path":"/1/classes/TestObject","body":[]},{"method":"POST","path":"/1/classes/TestObject","body":[]}]}

Which is valid JSON.

Batch actions worked properly before migrating. PHP version is 5.6.  Any help is appreciated. If the error can be reproduced, I will create an issue on GitHub.

Comment: Try removing the "/1"

Comment: @xissburg Thanks for your reply, but that didn't make a difference. I removed both "/1" and "/1/" and the error is the same. I'm stumped as to what could be causing the error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution was to write `/parse/classes/ClassName` instead of `/1/classes/ClassName`. So after migration, the details stated in the documentation at https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide, are outdated.

!!! this might change in the future !!! keep an eye on this issue: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-php-sdk/issues/229

Comment: In case you were writing to me rather than the general audience, I opened up that issue myself and the answer came up through there; though I hadn't checked out the issue page in a while and it looks like others are using the same solution. Thanks for the heads-up, should've answered it myself before.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case anyone is still looking for this, here's the solution posted over from github.

I dug into this a bit more. It turns out the server does some stripping on the urls it receives for batch requests. Specifically it checks to see that your api prefix (`/parse` in most cases) matches what was sent. With batch requests the individual requests do not contain this, and they end up failing this match. Testing out the code you put up above I was able to patch it up. It works, but I'll probably see if I can't write up a better patch in the future.

You currently need to prepend your api prefix as `/your_prefix/` (again in most cases this is `/parse`, but use the one you've set up for your server) in two places for batched saves and deletes as follows.

ParseObject.php `private static function deepSave($target, $useMasterKey = false)` (same place where /1/ is prepended)

```php
foreach ($requests as &$r) {
    $r['path'] = '/parse/' . $r['path'];
}
```

ParseObject.php `private static function destroyBatch(array $objects, $useMasterKey = false)`

```php
foreach ($objects as $object) {
    $data[] = [
        'method' => 'DELETE',
        'path'   => '/parse/classes/'.$object->getClassName().'/'.$object->getObjectId(),
    ];
}
```

With those two spots changed I was able to get batched saves & deletes running properly. I also observed the same issue you had before, just to confirm.